# What's the difference between depenencies and devDependencies with NPM 5

Tags: node.js, npm

The below question refers to a project I'm **not** publishing to `npm`.

In NPM 3, if I had a package in `devDependencies` and ran shrinkwrap (without `--development`) then `npm-shrinkwrap.json` would *not* include the packages in `devDependencies`.

But with NPM 5, packages in `dependencies` and `devDependencies` are added to `package-lock.json`, with those from `devDependencies` having `"dev": true`.

So, if I'm just using `npm install x` to add packages and `npm install` to install everything on, say, a build server, is a package listed in `dependencies` treated any differently from a package listed in `devDependencies`?

Answer (score 2):

It will make sense on production. When you'll need to install all packages, except dev.

```
npm i --production
```

From npmjs.org:

> With the --production flag (or when the NODE_ENV environment variable is set to production), npm will not install modules listed in devDependencies.